# Finding youtube HD movies using the Youtube API?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to determine if a certain video can be played in HD using the Youtube API?
And if not is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: Check http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Comment: Obviously I looked at it and couldn't find the answer. That's why I posted here

Answer (score 1):

Video can be played in HD if <yt:hd/> tag is present in entry.